# Is there a way to "stick" blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can someone "stick" blocks in Minecraft? I mean that if you push one with a piston, will it be possibly pushed together with other blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the item you are looking for is the [Slime Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime_block), added in version 1.8.

The slime block is a block, made from 9 slimeballs. When pushed or pulled by a piston, it will drag all adjacent blocks with it (up to the usual maximum of 12). Using multiple pistons, it is possible to build [vehicles](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Flying_technologies#Using_slime_blocks).

Comment: Beat me to the answer by 8 seconds. Same links and everything.

Comment: Thanks,but I already knew what's a slime block. @Studoku

Comment: @john Then what exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: I mean that I knew how it is built and that entities bounce on it,I was asking if simply csn stick blocks. Anyway,if someone builds a tank,he must repair it at every shot. @Studoku

Comment: @john If you put a slime block in between two other blocks, you can push or pull them with one piston. I'm not sure what tanks have to do with this.

Comment: I mean that someone can mount a tnt cannon on a vehicle. That is what I call tank. I once built one with some obsidian(to resist the blast),tnt,pistons and sticky pistons,but it didn't worked. Slime blocks have an awful blast resistance... @Studoku

Comment: @John That's an entirely different question to the one you asked.

Comment: @John And had you asked that, it'd have been much easier to point out that no, you can't. Neither obsidian nor dispensers can be moved by pistons (because dispensers have block entities and obsidian is too badass).